# $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure, and $|f_n|\le g\in L_\infty$, then $f=g$ almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure, and $|f_n|\le g\in L_\infty$, then $f=g$ almost everywhere

is it true: how to prove

if it is false: we need a counterexample.

we have tried a lot. but got stuck.

could you please help.

Comment: The problem is badly described. f_n→f In which function space and ubder which topology. What is F_n?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the question is poorly posed, take $f_n = 1/n$ and $g=1$ on $L^\infty[(1,2)]$. Clearly $|f_n| \leq g$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but $ 1/n \to 0 $ ($f_n \to f)$ and $ 0 \neq 1$.